# Industry Classification Mapping Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, assignment-rules, field-mapping

I'm seeking advice on optimizing our industry classification process. We use a set of 150+ industry classifications (Seasonality Industry) specific to a data source for industry seasonality analysis. These classifications have been mapped to standard Industry and Sub-Industry fields from ZoomInfo. The challenge arises when trying to automate the assignment of the Seasonality Industry to accounts upon their creation or update, based on their Industry and Sub-Industry information. The straightforward approach would require creating a cumbersome decision tree with 150+ choices and assignments.

An example is mapping Sub-Industry value "Dental Offices" to the Seasonality Industry value "Offices of dentists." I already have these mapped in a spreadsheet. If I wanted to do this function in excel I would use indexmatch or vlookup. It would be great if I could upload a .csv so I wouldn't have to match these 1 by 1.

Does anyone have experience with or can suggest a more efficient method to automate this process? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks - added the tag for apex. An example is mapping Sub-Industry value Dental Offices to the Seasonality Industry value Offices of dentists. I already have these mapped 1:1. If I wanted to do this function in excel I would use indexmatch or vlookup

Comment: Have you considered using custom metadata type to map the industry/subindustry values to the seasonality values?

Comment: Custom object(s): https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_modeling/object_relationships